# Fix WooCommerce Shop page rows

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming, woocommerce-theming

On my shop page on tablets and phones in landscape mode, not all products are shown next to each other. They leave gaps, so sometimes there are two products and sometimes just one product in a row. I tried around with CSS and couldn't find a solution. My goal is to have them all next to each other and display a minimum of 2 in a row on portrait phones, instead of one. How can I do this?

Here's my site: https://malimo.co/shop/

If you open the website on a computer screen, just make the browser window smaller and you will see it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set width of products to 50% + margin. That is more than width of screen.
On landscape you have this

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 560px)
    .theme__product__item--col__3:nth-child(3n) {
        margin-right: 15px;
}
```

change it to 0px

or change 50% to lower value. For example 46%.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 560px)
.theme__product__item--col__3 {
    width: calc(50% - 7.5px);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i think you should set margin-right to 10

```
@media (max-width: 767px) and (min-width: 560px)

.theme__product__item--col__3 {`

    width: calc(45% - 7.5px);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this will sort the issue. set margin-right to 0

```
 @media (max-width: 992px) and (min-width: 768px)
 {
   .theme__product__item--col__3:nth-child(3n) {
      margin-right: 0;
    }
 }
```